# how many variables are there from 9 digits excluding repeat numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

I have the numbers 1 to 9

I need to know how many different 9 digit code variations i would have using 1-9 but excluding any "next digit" replications.

example:

123456789 is acceptable

112345678 is not acceptable because there are two "1" in succession

every code must have 9 digits.

Answer (score 2):

You have $9$ options for the first digit. Since we don't want to repeat it, we have $8$ options of the next, for the same reason, we have $8$ options for each of the following numbers. Therefore we have:

$9·8^8 = 150994944$ different $9$ digit codes.

Comment: Thankyou, very much appreciated.

Comment: @Kieron Glad I could help!